# Keyboard shortcut or programmatic way of resizing frames in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Like a lot of folk I imagine, I'm looking at the VS default window layout on a 17" monitor. Fairly often, I want to grow the document frame to code, then grow the solution explorer or the output window to find stuff or look at output. It would be really cool if a modifier key + arrow keys moved the frame separators up and down, right and left. The [complete list](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/) of window shortcuts doesn't have anything to offer. Does anyone know about programmatic manipulation of the frame separator in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's such a key combination. You can, however, save a window layout and apply it with a keyboard shortcut, so you can save your common layouts.

Check the `Window -> Save Window Layout` and `Window -> Manage Window Layouts` commands to sort them. To apply, use the `Window -> Apply Window Layout`, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>) (not sure if 1-9, but I have 4 different layouts and at least 1-4 works)